# insert into value between xxx and yyy

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, range

Trying to tweak this query,

Inserting a range of rows into table, getting error msg,

> *"Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The statement has been terminated."*

Is the query correct or is there something else i'm missing?

```
insert into VCCUS (IDCUST,AUDTDATE,AUDTTIME,AUDTUSER,AUDTORG,FININVPDF,WHSINVPDF,WHSDDKPDF,FININVACT,WHSINVACT,WHSDDKACT)
values ((select idcust from ARCUS where IDCUST between '7016' and '7077'),20131204,2073088,'admin','BRIDAT',0,0,0,2,0,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this query

```
 insert into VCCUS (IDCUST,AUDTDATE,AUDTTIME,AUDTUSER,AUDTORG,FININVPDF,WHSINVPDF,WHSDDKPDF,FININVACT,WHSINVACT,WHSDDKACT) 
    select t1.idcust, t2.*  from
    (
    select idcust from ARCUS 
    where IDCUST between '7016' and '7077'
    ) t1
     CROSS JOIN
    (
    SELECT 20131204 AUDTDATE ,2073088 AUDTTIME ,'admin' AUDTUSER,
    'BRIDAT' AUDTORG ,0 FININVPDF,0 WHSINVPDF,0 WHSDDKPDF,2 FININVACT,0 WHSINVACT,0 WHSDDKACT) t2
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what this does... but Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'VCCUS_KEY_0'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.VCCUS'. The duplicate key value is (7057        ).
The statement has been terminated.